# Which slash should be used while saving a css file in css folder

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new to stack developer community.... I am not able to know which slash to use while saving a css file in css folder (/ or \) because I am currently learning web development and in that my professor when she creates a css file it something looks like ( css/style.css)
and in mine it looks like (css\style.css) .

I am currently using mine, should I change it to my professor one ??????

[this is the default css path that display in my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuygc.png)

Comment: This is a difference between UNIX based computers and Windows computers. Windows uses \ backslash in its filepaths and UNIX uses / forwardslash

Comment: MY teacher is using mac so still i can use my path which i have mention???

Comment: Correct, you can use the backslash if you are opening the website as a file. If you're using a development environment you can use the forward slash, ask your teacher when you're going to learn how to set that up.

Comment: Your backslash (\\) is not showing, as Markdown thinks that a backslash is an ignore character. To make your backslash show up, do a double-backslash (\\\).

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will accept the `/` as path separator on any popular platform. So there's no reason to use the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **any slash**. Either one will work fine.

All browsers (Google Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Brave, etc.) will support `/` as well as `\`, so there's no reason to be worried about which one to choose. Just choose whichever one which suits you.

---

If you want to know which slash to use when accessing a path locally, then read the below.

If you are using a *Unix*-based operating system (*macOS*, Linux), then both of those support forward-slashes in a path (`/`).

However, if you are using Windows, then it supports backslashes (`\`) in file paths.